# Owl-carousel and lightbox together? Or is there another solution?

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox, prettyphoto, owl-carousel

I would like to use [Owl-carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) and [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) lightbox together but before that, I would like to know if a similar all-in-one solution already exists.

To be more specific, I would like to make an inline image/video content slider gallery with caption on hover. It has to be `responsive` and `touchable` for mobile devices. If none exists yet, do Owl-carousel and PrettyPhoto work together without problems and is there a risk of conflict?

Thank's for any help.

Comment: This is how you can combine Owl-carousel and fancyBox3 -
 https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/mqvOoz?editors=1010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [my example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gableroux/gxG87/#base), I included a youtube video slider.

I did not test much but `Owl Carousel` and `PrettyPhoto` seem to work well together and it's actually a nice combo.

Here is a very basic example usage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    $(".owl-slider").owlCarousel();
});
```

You may also have a look on this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OGehUKEh/20/edit) I found for captions with owl carousel. I'm sure it's possible to merge both examples to get something out of it.

Good luck

Comment: Hi GabLe, I am trying to same. I am facing a problem when someone clicks on any image/logo in the carousel, It then stops autosliding. that problem is also there in your jsfiddle. when you click on any picture, It will stop auto-sliding the images, Let me know if there is any solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use 
[FooGallery](http://docs.fooplugins.com/foogallery/foogallery-owl-carousel-documentation/#slide2)

It has **lightbox and owl Carousel**